# shortcut for SQL Navigator 6.7.0 Professional Edition

Tags: sql-navigator

Is there a way to write sql commands with shortcuts.

For example, I will press ctrl+A, it writes like

```
"select * from database_name. "
```

I'm working with SQL Navigator 6.7.0 Professional Edition.

On Internet, some comments talk about tool -> preferences -> editor -> autoreplace. But, in my editor, preferences under the view section.

I couldn't find where I can do this short-cut.
Is there anybody have did that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also using SQL Navigator 6.7.0. It is a bit different as you mentioned, but not at all.

You can follow these steps;

View -> Preferences -> Code Editor -> General -> Templates

[image]